# import time from excel to matlab - milliseconds

Tags: excel, matlab, time, import, milliseconds

In an excel file I have the following date format: `3/31/2015 19:58:53.956`.

I cannot find a way to get the `milliseconds`. 
The format I get is `3/31/2015 '19:58:53`
Any ideas?

Comment: How do you import the data in MATLAB?

Comment: I second hbaderts, we need more information. Once you get your excel cells as strings, you need `datenum` and similar functions to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Matlab, but can you alter the Excel file with a column that calculates the Unix timestamp out of the date time column?

```
=(YOURCELL-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400000
```

86400000 is the number of milliseconds in a day. As far as i could check this works even for dates from over 15 years ago. E.g. Excel correctly converted 4/13/1999 22:22:22.345 to a Unix timestamp of [924042142345 milliseconds](http://currentmillis.com/?924042142345).